# Sharepoint edit form using $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser() not displaying until I move the mouse or hit a key

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a custom EditForm.aspx in which I am using Javascript to hide some rows for some users.  In order to determine the current user, I am calling $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser().  My code works perfectly on one server, but on a different one, it does this weird thing -- the edit page does not display until you do something like moving the mouse or hitting a key.  You just see a blank screen except for a blinking cursor where one of the text fields would be.  As soon as you move the mouse or hit a key, the page displays instantly.

To narrow the range of possibilities, I removed all javascript code except this single line

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/blah/blah/js/jquery.SPServices-0.5.8.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser()
</script>
```

from the page.  Comment it out, the page works normally.  Leave it in, and you get the weird behavior described above.  I tested the result of the function and it provides the current user correctly.  And again, on the other server, it works fine.

Ideas?

Comment: Did my answer help? If so, please accept so others know it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the SPServices.js file, you will notice that the function extends a few options. One of which is the fieldName. You should pass it a fieldName like maybe Title which will return the person Full Name. The problem is though, that is data does not exists, it seems to break. I dont think there is really a "returns false when empty" feature to it.

```
var userName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
fieldName: "Title"
});
```

[SPGetCurrentUser Wiki](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser)