# SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser not working in IE browser

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, spservices

This code is not working in IE 9 but works in Chrome and FireFox. What changes can I make to work this code in IE?

```
var thisUserAccount = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
fieldName: "Name",
debug: false
});
```

Comment: What does the console say? Are you running under HTTPS?

Comment: No. I am not running under HTTPS. There is also no error reported in IE. I am updating this variable "thisUserAccount" in a textbox which works in all browsers except IE

Comment: Ok.. I think you're running into browser compatability issues here.. SPServices seems to have vague support towards Internet Explorer with versions lower than 10..

Comment: Just now tried in IE 10 and IE 11. Still not working.

Comment: I am out of good ideas.. maybe look at these to get some more input.. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878725/sharepoint-edit-form-using-spservices-spgetcurrentuser-not-displaying-unti), [link2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79784/i-am-using-spservices-spgetcurrentuser-to-get-the-current-user-but-its-no), [link3](https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions?searchText=spgetcurrentuser)